# why the model bean is not found in the spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

My question is, isn't an object created from the model in spring? So why does it give an error when it tries to inject in the following program?

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {
    private final ContactService service;
    private Model model;

    public ContactController(ContactService service, Model model) {
        this.service = service;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @GetMapping("contact")
    public String displayPage() {
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        return "contact";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
but this works! It means that the bean is created.(Of course, after we delete the model field from the constructor and the class)

```
@GetMapping("contact")
    public String displayPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        return "contact";

    }
```

error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.isoft.controllers.ContactController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.ui.Model' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.ui.Model' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is not a dependency to your controller. You need to return a new model, when the method is called. Otherwise, different requests would all see the same model (race-conditions, security issues, and all other kinds of nasty problems)

```java
@Controller
public class ContactController {
    private final ContactService service;

    public ContactController(final ContactService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("contact")
    public String displayPage() {
        final Model model = new Model();
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        return "contact";
    }
}
```

When defining the model as dependency in the constructor, a bean of that type (and name) is looked up in the application context. Only a single instance in injected.

However, the model is request-specific and therefore needs to be injected into the handler method itself. Think `@Scope("request")`.

```
    @GetMapping("contact")
    public String displayPage(final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        return "contact";
    }
```

More details can be found in the Spring Web MVC framework docs: [17.3 Implementing Controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)

Comment: I think you can also remove the `private Model model` from your example as well.

Comment: @knittl The problem is that when I pass the model as an argument to the method parameters, it works correctly! That is, it looks like the bean is created and injected. I have updated the question for this situation.

Comment: @munknown It's not a bean. It's a model bound to your HTTP request.